# I'm getting "Unknown setting session_id" while connecting to ClickHouse from IDE DataGrip

Tags: clickhouse, datagrip

I'm trying to connect to ClickHouse from IDE [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/). But that doesn't work and I'm receiving this error:

```
Code: 115, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown setting session_id, e.what() = DB::Exception.
```

How would be possible to solve this? Could it be some internal IDE pre-sets?

Comment: What is the version of ClickHouse you're trying to connect to? Which version of IDE DataGrid do you use?

Comment: which tool did you use - IntelliJ IDEA or DataGrip? where did you define this param?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define this setting in URL of *'Data Sources and Drivers' -> 'Data Sources' -> General* section:

[image]

```sh
jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123/?session_id=test_01&session_timeout=3600
```